# Python scientific notation using lower case 'e' instead of 'E' .to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm calculating FX rates in Python.

Doing a really simple calculation of `rate = currency_1_rate/currency_2_rate` (where rates for both currencies are just a decimal number), which is returning a rate in scientific notation with a lower case 'e'.

For example IDR to USD rate is being returned as: 6.87758e-05

Is there a way to get python to output these numbers/rates using a capital E for the scientific notation instead? There are processes further down the line that might not accept this lower case 'e' notation.

I am doing a pandas .to_csv with these rates, so ideally don't to be converting to a string then back to a number.

I've also tried adding: `df.to_csv("path/to/file.csv", float_format="E")`
Which returns error: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" - any ideas why this might not be working? Or how to work around this?

Comment: `float_format` expects a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) like `'%.3f'` or `'%g'` which is telling `to_csv` how floats should be written. You probably want to use `'%E'`

Comment: It now seems to be converting ALL numbers to scientific notation. Is there a way for it to only convert numbers that are already in scientific notation to a capital E?

Comment: @Jerry12345678 did you try my solution?

Answer (score -2):

There may be a nicer way to do it by using the settings on `to_csv`.

A brute force method would be to explicitly cast the columns as a string and replace `e` with `E`:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = zip(range(5), range(10000000, 60000000, 10000000))

columns = ('a', 'b')

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

# your decimal column
df['c'] = df['a'] / df['b']

# convert to str and replace e-->E
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(str).str.replace('e', 'E')

df
```